# How to generate bounce-back email notification, with some extra info included

Tags: c#, email, notifications, email-bounces

I am just now beginning to research this, and so far haven't come up with much. So, I'm hoping you guys can help me, or point me in some sort of direction.

I am in a situation in which I need to somehow be able to detect a failed email delivery and/or bounced-back email. Then, I need to be able to sent out a notification email describing this failure, as well as include some other, specific information in the notification email as well.

At the moment, I really have no idea how to do this. The email system we have now involves some C#.NET managed code, which send the email via an SMTP Exchange server. So, my initial thoughts are that I might be able to use email header information to accomplish this, but I'm not terribly family with all of the available email headers. I am also not at all opposed to finding and using some sort of third-party solution, but again, I'm not familiar with any such solutions or solution providers, and so I am very open to suggestions there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to download messages from an IMAP server or a POP3 server. If it's the case, you may want to check out the [Ultimate Bounce Inspector component](http://www.codeultimate.com/component/bounceinspector.net/). It also let you process EML files.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the SMTPClient class? If so, there's a SmtpFailedRecipientsException that would help you accomplish what you need.

Examples and further information given here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception.aspx

Comment: I never know that something like this will happen unless you dont mention it. Thanks though it is not supported by most of the client

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PostMark](http://openmymind.net/2010/7/21/Using-PostMark-To-Send-Mail) which allows you to programmatically process bounced emails.